# Calculating time after pressing button (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a reaction test website just for fun, but I don't know how to calculate the time taken between button presses.

I found this

```js
var startTime;

function startButton() {
    startTime = Date.now();
}

function stopButton() {
    if (startTime) {
        var endTime = Date.now();
        var difference = endTime - startTime;
        alert('Reaction time: ' + difference + ' ms');
        startTime = null;
    } else {
        alert('Click the Start button first');
    }
}
```

but it only works for 2 buttons (I only want one). So I tried making a function, something like

```
function calculateTime(){
startButton();
stopButton();
}
```

but of course, it doesn't work since it will stop the timer immediately. Any way to get around it?

Comment: If i get you correctly, you want both functions to run on one button click and not two?

Comment: Replace the alert command with the `startTime = Date.now();` line, then set `stopButton` as click handler for the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single function that checks whether `startTime` has been set or not. If it hasn't been set, it sets it; otherwise, it reports the time difference.

```js
let startTime = null;

const button = document.querySelector("#timer");
button.addEventListener("click", startStop);
const output = document.querySelector("#output");

function startStop() {
  if (startTime) {
    var endTime = Date.now();
    var difference = endTime - startTime;
    output.innerText = 'Reaction time: ' + difference + ' ms';
    startTime = null;
    button.innerText = "Start Timer";
  } else {
    startTime = Date.now();
    button.innerText = "Stop Timer";
    output.innerText = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="timer">Start Timer</button><br>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I see. So I don't have to call startStop() at all since addEventListener will be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use performace.now() or console.time to calucalte time after press button.

```js
var performance = window.performance;
var t0 = performance.now();
------your function--------
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("This function took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
```

```js
function a() {
  console.time("buttontimer");
  ... your function ...
  var dur = console.timeEnd("buttontimer"); // NOTE: dur only works in FF
}
```

Comment: What is `doWork()` supposed to do? They want to calculate the time difference to another click.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You need to declare the start time outside of the function so that it persists between function calls and then use the `else` section of the `if` statement to set it.

```js
let startTime;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", startStop);

function startStop() {
    if (startTime) {
        console.log("Clock stopped");    
        var endTime = Date.now();
        var difference = endTime - startTime;
        alert('Reaction time: ' + difference + ' ms');
        startTime = null;
    } else {
        startTime = Date.now();
        console.log("Clock started");
    }
}
```

```html
<button>Start/Stop</button>
```